# Why does the code not put anything into the array?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, append

I am trying to create a program which will work like a shop, but for some reason it doesn't put anything into the array when I want it to.

The csv file that I am using looks like this:

```
24937597    Basic Hatchet   20
49673494    Hardened Axe    100
73165248    Steel Axe       500
26492186    Utility Truck   2000
54963726    Small Trailer   600
17667593    Shabby Sawmill  200
76249648    SawMax 01       5000
34865729    Basic Hammer    70
46827616    50mm Nails      0.10
46827623    20mm Nails      0.05
```

My code looks like this:

```
import csv
import time

retry='yes'
while retry=='yes':

    receipt=[]
    total=0
    numofitems=0

    with open ('Stock File.csv','r') as stock:
        reader=csv.reader(stock, delimiter=',')

        print('Welcome to Wood R Us. Today we are selling:')
        print(' ')
        print('GTIN-8 code  Product name  Price')
        for row in reader:
            print(row[0]+'  '+row[1]+'  '+row[2])
        print(' ')

        choice='product'
        while choice=='product':
            inputvalid='yes'
            barcode=input('Enter the GTIN-8 code of the product you wish to purchase: ')
            quantity=int(input('Enter the quantity you wish to purchase: '))
            for row in reader:
                if barcode in row:
                    cost=int(row[2])
                    price=quantity*cost
                    total=total+price
                    receipt.append(barcode+row[1]+str(quantity)+row[2]+str(price))
                    numofitems=numofitems+1

            print('Do you want to buy another product or print the receipt?')
            choice=input('product/receipt ')

        if choice=='receipt':
            inputvalid='yes'
            for i in range(0, numofitems):
                print(str(receipt[i]))
                time.wait(0.5)
            print(' ')
            print('Total cost of order     '+str(total))

        else:
            inputvalid='no'

        if inputvalid=='no':
            print('Invalid input')

        if inputvalid=='yes':
            print(' ')
            print('Do you want to make another purchase?')
            retry=input('yes/no ')
        while retry!='yes':
            while retry!='no':
                print(' ')
                print('Invalid input')
                print('Do you want to make another purchase?')
                retry=input('yes/no ')
            retry='yes'
        retry='no'
if retry=='no':
    print('Goodbye! See you again soon!')
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you use string values when there are built-in boolean values?

Comment: Why are you trying to loop over `reader` repeatedly?

Comment: what array ? `receipt=[]` ? use `print()` to check values in variables in different places of code. Maybe you delete all values using `receipt=[]` in wrong palce.

Comment: Notice that you do `for row in reader` twice. The entire file is exhausted the first time round so there is nothing for the second one to do. You may want to exit the with block as soon as you print stuff and do another one for the rest of the code. You could also add a `stock.seek(0)` in there.

Comment: Are you aware that your csv file has only one column?  There are no commas in it.

Comment: @Darthfett I have the csv file which works for all of my other codes. I just put it that way to make it look neater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `stock.seek(0)` at line 26: `for row in reader:` before reading the `csv`'s rows again.

`csv.reader()` objects behave like python's `file.read()` method in that the file reader needs to be reset to the beginning of the file before reading the file contents again. Before checking the user's input at line `while choice=='product':`, you had already read through the `csv` file once at line `17`:

```
for row in reader:
    ...
```

and the `csv.reader()` object is still pointing at the end of the `csv` file's contents, and there are no more rows for the reader to read, so the code never enters into the next `for row in reader:` loop.

To fix it, insert a `stock.seek(0)` statement before reading the `csv` contents again, at `if barcode in row:`, will reset the `csv.reader()` to the beginning of the file and you should see items fill your array.